# Reverse order of words in a sentence without using built in functions

Tags: php, logic

I had an interview and a question that seems really simple was not clicking in my mind. Just want to get the answer for it because have tried a lot and unable to find solution.

I have to write a sentence in opposite like

```
input => My Name Is Junaid
output => Junaid Is Name My
```

Should not use ANY built-in function of PHP

Thanks

**EDIT**

I did upto this

```
$string = "My Name Is Junaid";
$len = strlen($string);
for($i=$len; $i > 0; $i--){
    echo $string[$i-1];
}
```

it results

```
dianuJ sI emaN yM
```

need some more tweaking

Comment: "Should not use ANY built-in function of PHP". So how can i write ?

Comment: echo isn't a function in php, it's a language construct... therefore you can use echo.... that's a starting point, now you just need to shuffle the input without using any function... suggest use of loops, $string[$value] and if tests for space matching

Comment: oh sorry i meant to say built-in array functions like explode

Comment: @MarkBaker so only `echo`, `if condition`, `loop`, `array` ?

Comment: @safaroz - plus array[] assignment, break, variable assignment, incrementor... don't think anything else is needed

Comment: @Junaid could you please add "without using built in functions" to the title, it's misleading and people looking for an simpler answer would have a hard time searching for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = "My Name is Fred";
$i = 0;
while( $d = $str[$i] )
{
    if( $d == " "){

        $out = " ".$temp.$out;
        $temp = "";
    }else{
        $temp.=$d;

    }
    $i++;
}
echo $temp.$out;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$name = 'shashank is a good boy';
$i = 0;
while($name[$i] != '')
{
    $i++;
}
$len = $i;
for ($j=$len; $j>0; $j--){
    echo $name[$j-1];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's possible, using control structures. Without strlen, too. It will just produce one notice-level error.

I am quite sure it can be done nicer, but here is quick solution, without ANY php function, just control structures.

```
$string = 'My Name Is Junaid';
 $i = 0;
 $output = array('');
 $output_index = 1;
 while (true) {
    $char = $string{$i};
    $i++;
    if ($char == ' ') {
        $output[$output_index] = '';
        $output_index++;
    } elseif ($char === '') {
        break;
    } else {
        $output[$output_index - 1] .= $char;
    }
 }

 for ($i = $output_index; $i--; $i >= 0) {
     echo $output[$i];
     echo ' ';
 }
```

Comment: PHP strings are not C strings, they can contain easily a \0 anywhere inside them. From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php "There are no limitations on the values the string can be composed of; in particular, bytes with value 0 (“NUL bytes”) are allowed anywhere in the string"

Can you still code it without `strlen`?

Comment: Hey its working but with just one notice at
`$char = $string{$i};`
saying
`Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 17` its the last character, thiking about it and praising your quick effort 

on quick question: you have used { } in this line I have never used such syntax can you please shed some lights on it or name what its called so I do some research over it

Regards

Comment: @mrtj well, yes, thanks for pointing it out. I shall edit my code now.

Comment: @Junaid I am afraid you'll have to use `strlen`

Comment: @junaid it is not different from [] used on a string. It is a reference to char on position $i

Comment: Ok, now remains only the out-of-bounds warning :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function reverse_string($str) {
  while ($str[$i]) {
    if ($str[$i] != '~') {
      $rstr = $str[$i] . $rstr;
      $str[$i] = '~';
    }
    ++$i;
  }
  return $rstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$rev = array("vignesh");
    foreach ($rev as $name)
     {
        echo $name[6];
        echo $name[5];
        echo $name[4];
        echo $name[3];
        echo $name[2];
        echo $name[1];
        echo $name[0];
    }

?>
```

### OUTPUT:

hsengiv

Answer (score 0):

This way you can reduce the number of cycle hence saving will be performance efficient

```
<?php
$str = "My Name is Aman jain";
$p = explode(' ',$str);

for ($i= (count($p)-1); $i >= 0  ; $i--) { 
   echo $p[$i]. ' ';
}
```

Comment: Uses explode() - not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This :

```
$str = "NAHUAHC PATARP NAMUSNA si eman YM";
$reverseStr = "";
$length = 0;
while (isset($str[$length])) {
    $reverseStr = $str[$length] . $reverseStr;
    $length++;
}
print $reverseStr;
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look the below code: Reverse the string

```
   $str = 'abcdefg';
    $reverseString = '';
    for($i=strlen($str);$i<=strlen($str);$i--){
      $reverseString .= $str[$i];
    if($i==0)
    break;
    }

    echo $reverseString;
```

The above code output is:

```
gfedcba
```

Answer (score -2):

Iterate from the end towards the through the input chars by chars (with []) searching for spaces (or any white chars). If found one, save the position. When found the second one, add the characters between the two positions to the output. At least `strlen` you will need, if you can use also `substr`:

```
<?php
$input = "My Name Is Junaid";
$output = "";
$lastpos = strlen($input);
for ($i = strlen($input) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  if ($input[$i] == ' ') {
    if (strlen($output) > 0) $output .= ' ';
    $output .= substr($input, $i + 1, $lastpos - $i);
    $lastpos = $i;
  }
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Uses strlen - that's not allowed, is it?

Comment: "oh sorry i meant to say built-in array functions like explode" - by the questioner above. Without `strlen` you can solve it only with out of bounds warnings.

Answer (score -2):

You can reverse the whole string using for cycle

```
$str2 = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++)
    $str2 .= $str[strlen($str)-$i-1];
```

and then, look up each word (between whitespaces), and reverse those with the same algorithm.

Comment: oh, really, and how would you iterate without knowing length? (and without any warning in strict mode?)

Comment: Which part of question is about warnings? It is an interview question, not real-life application.

Comment: I'm asking the same question during interviews. If someone answered the way you did, I'd fire him immediately. String length is basic knowledge, and the question should be language-independent.

Comment: "oh sorry i meant to say built-in array functions like explode" - by the questioner above. Without `strlen` you can solve it only with out of bounds warnings.