# get every words backwards using php

Tags: php, html

I want to get the text and print every words backwards.

Example: `Hello World`

Output: `World hello`

This is my codes so far. It is different, I get output backwards but per string.

```
$string = "hello world";  

$length = strlen($string);  
for ($i=($length-1) ; $i >= 0 ; $i--)   
{  
  echo $string[$i];  
}
```

Output of the above code is:

```
dlrow olleh
```

Comment: Dupe with unrealistic limitation of allowed functions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9907533/2943403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to do it with `array_reverse()`,

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello World';
$strArray = explode(" ", $str);       
$strArray = array_reverse($strArray);       
$str = implode($strArray, " ");
echo $str;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ZfEqQ